# Spring boot 2.2.4 spy bean integration test is not a Mockito mock

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin, mockito

In my free time I'm migrating from spring boot 1.5 to newsest (2.2.4). I think I'm pretty close to the end. Having this dependencies:

> org.mockito:mockito-core:2.28.2
>
> org.mockito:mockito-junit-jupiter:2.18.3
>
> com.nhaarman.mockitokotlin2:mockito-kotlin:2.2.0
>
> org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:2.2.4.RELEASE

Currently forcing problem probably with `@SpyBean`

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner::class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
class abc {

    @SpyBean
    lateinit var abcRepository: AbcRepository
    enter code here
    ...
    @Test
    fun test {
        ...
        val abcCaptor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(Abc::class.java)
        verify(abcRepository, times(2)).save(abcCaptor.capture())
    }
```

And the error is. As I can see in debug department repository is `Proxy -> SimpleJpaRepository`

```
VerificationStartedEvent.setMock() does not accept parameter which is not a Mockito mock.
  Received parameter: org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository@7f48943b.
  See the Javadoc.
```

Comment: After some googling, I've found this thread on GitHub : https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/7033
The best way to solve this would be, as you are doing a full test, to check your databases entry.

Comment: But this code was working with spring boot 1.5

Comment: Are you still your test with junit4 or junit5 ? if junit5, try removing the `@RunWith`. If not, try making your test run with junit5